# Searching within nested list Scheme/Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define-struct school (name students))
;; An SchoolChart is a (make-school Str (listof SchoolChart))
;; names are unique
```

I have a school chart say

```
(define s-chart (make-school "Tom" (list 
(make-school "James" empty) 
(make-school "Claire" 
    (make-school "David" empty) 
    (make-school "Travis" empty)) 
(make-school "Timmy" empty))))
```

This is a general tree, say I define a function

```
(define (find-name name school)) ;;produces true if found/false if not.
```

How do I go about the recursion? This specific case is fine, but each child can have infinite children? I just need a hint

Comment: If you are searching you check if the current node is your answer, else you check if each of the children using recursion, when no node left and nothing found you return a false or something to indicate failure. Ps: for infinite children recursion won't help so it cannot be that. If you meant cycles then you need a structure to know the visited nodes.

Answer (score 1):

There can only be a finite amount of children.
The amount is arbitrary and only bounded by your machine's memory, but it can't be infinite.

(And your `s-chart` is ill-formed, since "Claire"'s children are not a list.)

The recursion can be pretty simple.
Here's a depth-first search:

```
(define (find-name name school)
    (or (string=? name (school-name school))
        (any (lambda (s) (find-name name s)) (school-students school))))
```

where `(any p ls)` is `#t` if and only if `(p e)` is `#t` for at least one element `e` of the list `ls`.

Now all that remains is to write `any`...

Answer (score 0):

Following recursively checks all items and, if found, add the name to a list outside the loop. However, it needs to use `set!`. It uses `string-prefix?` instead of `string=?` for demonstration purposes (to get more names in the current structure):

```
(define-struct school (name students))

(define s-chart
  (make-school "Tom"
               (list 
                (make-school "James" empty) 
                (make-school "Claire" (list
                                       (make-school "David" empty) 
                                       (make-school "Travis" empty)))
                (make-school "Timmy" empty))))


(define (find-name name school)
  (define ol '())
  (let loop ((s school))
    (cond
      [(list? s)
       (when (not(empty? s))
           (begin (loop (first s))
                  (loop (rest s))))]
      [else
       (when (string-prefix? (school-name s) name)
         (set! ol (cons (school-name s) ol)))
       (loop (school-students s))
         ]))
  ol
  )

(find-name "T" s-chart)
```

Output:

```
'("Timmy" "Travis" "Tom")
```